# Android background process to trigger a code

Tags: android, android-service

I need a sample code or example which shows a proper implementation of services. I want to run a code after a interval of time, say 3-4 hrs. and the process should run in background and also even the device is rebooted.

I have come-up with the option `bootreciever` and `boot_completed`, but really don't know how to implement it or the `async` function to the running process to run again and again after an interval.

manifest

```
<service
            android:name=".Myservice"
            android:label="My Service" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.app.ader.Myservice" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


        <receiver android:name="com.app.ader.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver">  
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
    </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

Myservice.java

```
public class Myservice extends Service {

    String tag="TestService";
       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();
           Toast.makeText(this, "Service created...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
           Log.i(tag, "Service created...");
       }

       @Override
       public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {      
           super.onStart(intent, startId);  
           Log.i(tag, "Service started...");
       }
       @Override
       public void onDestroy() {
           super.onDestroy();
           Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

       @Override
       public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
           return null;
       }
    }
```

StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver.java

```
public class StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, Myservice.class);
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

My services are running after boot...but i even need to run the service after installation of the application. Dunno how to implement that nd as well as the Alarm manager???interval of 3-4 hrs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In your  element:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

2) In your  element (be sure to use a fully-qualified [or relative] class name for your BroadcastReceiver):

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.MyBroadcastReceiver">  
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
    </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

In MyBroadcastReceiver.java:

```
package com.example;

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        startServiceIntent.addaction("com.app.ader.Myservice");
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

3)Within Your Service Start the Alarmmanager in Service OnStart().Hope this clarify your things

Comment: okay..i have done exactly what u said...and this is my service code-

Comment: but nuthing happens as in the toast i decraled...so i guess service isnt runnin???

Comment: you have provide intent filter to your service.<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.app.ader.Myservice" />
            </intent-filter> see updated code

Comment: @user2990564:Pleasure to help you.

Comment: nd how to implement timer function??

Comment: take a look at this link-you need to use Alarmanager for timer functionality.http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/

Answer (score 1):

You are on right path. Create a service for code execution. Also create a receiver which triggers when boot is completed, then start the service from it. Also use Alarm Manager's `setRepeating` method to repetitively call the service.

Start one by one

1) Create Simple Service

2) Create Receiver which starts service after boot completion.

3) At last create Alarm Manager

Comment: thankyou for the reply..but um kinda new to services nd this type of recievers...could you be more specific??